# Laravel Mix (v6.16.0) ignores tailwind.config.js (v1.2.0) settings

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-mix, tailwind-css, laravel-ui

I am using laravel/framework v6.16.0, laravel/ui v1.2.0 and TailwinCSS v1.2.0. For setting up, I used the instructions from https://sandulat.com/blog/installing-tailwind-into-laravel/. After minor adjustments concerning the namings, like

- `tailwind.js` => `tailwind.config.js`
- `@tailwind preflight;` => `@tailwind base;`
- `@import 'tailwind';` => `@import 'tailwindcss';`

everything seemed to work fine and the TailwindCSS classes take effect. My only problem is, that all changes I made in tailwind.config.js are ignored. The files are recompiled (`npm run watch`), but the changes from tailwind.config.js are not adopted. There are no error messages or other indications.

If I provoke a syntax error in tailwind.config.js, I get an error message. Therefore I conclude that the file is parsed, but as I mentioned without any effect.

Can someone tell me where to start troubleshooting or better tell me where the error could be?

Comment: Does stopping and restarting the `watch` command work?

Comment: Unfortunally not, I tried it several times.

Comment: Update: Now using Laravel Framework v7.14.1 and tailwindcss v1.4.6 ans still all changes in tailwind.config.js are ignored, such as theme => extend => colors etc. I am completely at a loss...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, installing https://github.com/laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

These settings are working for me in a fresh project with Laravel 8, Mix 6, and Tailwind v2:

**tailwind.config.js**

This file is unmodified except for the added purge settings:

```
module.exports = {
    purge: [
        'resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
        'resources/js/**/*.js',
        './resources/**/*.vue',
    ],
    darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    variants: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

**webpack.mix.js**

This file is unmodified except for the import for tailwind and the appended tailwind settings. Watchout for that extra `{}` in the second parameter there.

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css', {}, [
        tailwindcss('tailwind.config.js'),
    ])
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
    });
```

**app.scss**

I just added all three tailwind directives for now. The output is quite large, so some editing may be recommended.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

The URL in the other answer was critical to making it work. This one here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/multiple-tailwind-configs-for-theming

Answer (score 1):

This Laracasts user's comment:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/multiple-tailwind-configs-for-theming
solved this issue for me.

I needed to call mix.sass with [tailwindcss: **configfile**] as the third parameter. Using the same in .options did not work.